# homebrew install php56 --with-httpd24 fails on OS 10.12 with make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1 [install-recursive] Error 1

Tags: php, installation, homebrew

I'm trying to install php56 with the httpd24 option so that I can use the the mod_php apache module in Mac OS Sierra (10.12.2).

When I run this command: `brew install php56 --with-httpd24` make fails while building http24. The last few lines of the make log are:

```
Last 15 lines from /Users/Dash/Library/Logs/Homebrew/httpd24/03.make:
make[4]: Nothing to be done for `local-shared-build'.
Building shared: mod_heartbeat.la mod_heartmonitor.la
make[4]: Nothing to be done for `local-shared-build'.
Building shared: mod_dav.la
make[4]: Nothing to be done for `local-shared-build'.
Building shared: mod_status.la mod_autoindex.la mod_asis.la mod_info.la mod_suexec.la mod_cgi.la mod_cgid.la
make[4]: Nothing to be done for `local-shared-build'.
Building shared: mod_dav_fs.la
make[4]: Nothing to be done for `local-shared-build'.
Building shared: mod_dav_lock.la
make[4]: Nothing to be done for `local-shared-build'.
Building shared: mod_vhost_alias.la mod_negotiation.la mod_dir.la mod_actions.la mod_speling.la mod_userdir.la mod_alias.la mod_rewrite.la
make[4]: Nothing to be done for `local-shared-build'.

make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

Comment: You should consider posting this on [Super User](http://superuser.com) instead of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my setup, it turned out there was a symlink: `/usr/local/var/www` that was causing make to crash during a recursive command.

`rm /usr/local/var/www` allowed httpd24 to build successfully.
See: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-apache/issues/143

Comment: Thank you! This was vexing me for days.